# Small set with dot product $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and $A$ be the set of all non-zero vectors of the form $(e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n)$, where $ e_i\in\{0,1\}$. So $|A|=2^n-1$. Find the smallest possible size of a set $B\subseteq A$ for which there does not exist a subset $C\subseteq A$ of size at most $n-2$ such that for any vector in $b\in B$, there exists a vector $c\in C$ with $c\cdot b=1$?

If $n-2$ were changed to $n-1$, this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248828/there-exists-a-vector-c-in-c-with-c-cdot-b-1) shows that we need $B$ to be the whole set $A$, which has size $2^{n}-1$. So I guess the answer is $2^{n-1}-1$. If we take all vectors in $A$ with last coordinate zero, then we do have a set of size $2^{n-1}-1$ which needs $|C|=n-2$. So suppose $|B|\leq 2^{n-1}-2$. Now there are a lot of vectors in $A$ that are missing in $B$, so it's not clear how to find the vectors to include in $C$.